# Reading MSC (MIDI show control)

Tags: c, midi

can anyone think of a method or library that would allow me to sense and read [MSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_Show_Control) that is [outputted from the ion lighting console](http://www.etcconnect.com/Support/Articles/Understanding-the-MSC-Commands-Eos-Family-Receives-and-Transmits.aspx)

Comment: Those are MIDI messages. Handle them like any other MIDI message.

Comment: @cl so I could just use win32? (Assuming I am using a windows computer)

Comment: So you want to know how to receive MIDI messages in general?

Comment: No thanks, found a lot of threads about how to receive MIDI messages already

Comment: @user3250068 Yes, you can use whatever you are using to send/receive any other MIDI messages, such as the Win32 API.